# Query outputs in command line but not in phpadmin and PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SELECT statement with several SELECTs inside. It runs fine in the command line, it produces the correct results, but does not output anything, blank only, in phpmyadmin or in my PHP script. It seems that it cannot output the result when sent to the browser?? I already set max_execution_time = 1200 and memory_limit = 1024M in php.ini but still does not work.

What seems to be the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Check your error logs. The query fails in `phpmyadmin`? Your PHP script works from command line or the query using the `mysql` CLI?

Comment: There is no mysql error, it just did not display the result in phpmyadmin but the results are displayed when I run the query in the command line.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin. You've offered no code and have a very broad trouble statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late response. I found an answer to my question. :) It was my fault also that I did not specify that I was using Codeigniter with an old version.

I found an answer somewhere here in stackoverflow weeks ago I forgot the link. The old version of CI overides the execution time set by Php. So to change the execution time:

```
In system/core/Codeigniter.php, line 106 in version 2.1.3 the following appears:

if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(900);
}
```

It solved my problem. For the newer version, CI updated this setting. :)